# Why does not JS background colour of input field check work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if the background colour of an input field is e.g. green when the input is changed. I have tried most things, but nothing seems to work. Why does this not work? I think it is the condition in the if statement that does not work, as I have tried both alert and value inside the if statement.
The following is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
function myFunction(chosenID) {
  if (document.getElementById(chosenID).style.backgroundColor == "#99ff99") {
    document.getElementById(chosenID).value = "You tried to change a form with a background colour already"
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="a" value="Non-coloured input field" onChange="myFunction('a')">
  <input type="text" id="b" value="Coloured input field" onChange="myFunction('b')" style="background-color: #99ff99">
</body>

</html>
```

#### Edit

I do not think that this is a duplicate. My question is about not getting the desired result from a function, not about conversion between RGB and HEX. Therefore, this should be reopened.

Comment: If you log out the value of `document.getElementById(chosenID).style.backgroundColor` you'll see the problem, the browser is returning the colour in RGB rather than hex.

Comment: This is easy if you know how to debug. See [Debug JavaScript - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

Comment: Also, you should probably use `getComputedStyle()` to encompass all CSS and inline styling. - `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(chosenID)).backgroundColor`

Comment: try this `element.style.getPropertyValue('background-color')`

Comment: myInputTypeObj = document.getElementById("choosenID"); 
    const myInputTypeObjBgColor = window.getComputedStyle(myInputTypeObj).backgroundColor;
    alert(myInputTypeObjBgColor);


    if(myInputTypeObjBgColor == "rgb(0, 128, 0)")
     {
     //your condition
     }

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov That did unfortunately not work.